# Why is this Interpreter Restriction failing?

Tags: curated-data, interpreter

Why is the following interpreter restriction on City failing?

```
Interpreter[Restricted["City",Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Washington","UnitedStates"}]]]["Shoreline"]
Interpreter["City"]["Shoreline"]
Entity["City",{"Shoreline","Washington","UnitedStates"}]["AdministrativeDivision"]
```

> Failure["RestrictionFailure",  Association[  "MessageTemplate" :>
>   MessageName[Interpreter, "geomember1"],    "MessageParameters" ->
>   Association[    "Polygon" -> "Washington, United States", "Input" ->
>   "Shoreline"],    "Region" -> Entity[    "AdministrativeDivision",
>   {"Washington", "UnitedStates"}],    "Input" -> "Shoreline"]]
>
> Entity["City", {"Shoreline", "Washington", "UnitedStates"}]
>
> Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Washington", "UnitedStates"}]

I am trying to Semantically Import a dataset and some of the interpreters when restricted don't seem to be capturing the required regions.

---

Another example:

```
Interpreter[Restricted["ZIPCode",Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Washington","UnitedStates"}]]]["98119"]
Interpreter["ZIPCode"]["98119"]
Entity["ZIPCode","98119"]["USStates"]
```

> Failure["RestrictionFailure",  Association[  "MessageTemplate" :>
>   MessageName[Interpreter, "geomember1"],    "MessageParameters" ->
>   Association[    "Polygon" -> "Washington, United States", "Input" ->
>   "98119"],    "Region" -> Entity[    "AdministrativeDivision",
>   {"Washington", "UnitedStates"}],    "Input" -> "98119"]]
>
> Entity["ZIPCode", "98119"]
>
> {Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Washington", "UnitedStates"}]}

---

Using @ciao technique to give an explicit list of cities in the required region to `Interpreter` makes the above cases work but now I found another issue:

```
Interpreter["City"]["Preston"]
Interpreter[Restricted["City",Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Washington","UnitedStates"}]]]["Preston"]
Interpreter[Restricted["City",{GeoEntities[Entity["AdministrativeDivision",{"Washington","UnitedStates"}],"City"]}]]["Preston"]
```

> Entity["City", {"Preston", "Lancashire", "UnitedKingdom"}]
>
> Failure["RestrictionFailure",  Association[  "MessageTemplate" :>
>   MessageName[Interpreter, "geomember1"],    "MessageParameters" ->
>   Association[    "Polygon" -> "Washington, United States", "Input" ->
>   "Preston"],    "Region" -> Entity[    "AdministrativeDivision",
>   {"Washington", "UnitedStates"}],    "Input" -> "Preston"]]
>
> Failure["RestrictionFailure", <|"MessageTemplate" :>
>   Interpreter::choice, "MessageParameters" -> <|"Choices" -> "Aberdeen
>   Gardens, Aberdeen, Acme, Ahtanum, Airway Heights, ..., Zillah", 
>       "Value" -> "Preston", "Input" -> "Preston"|>, "Choices" -> {Entity["City",{"AberdeenGardens","Washington","UnitedStates"}],...,Entity["City",{"Zillah","Washington","UnitedStates"}]},
>   "Value" -> Entity["City",{"Preston","Lancashire","UnitedKingdom"}],
>   "Input" -> "Preston"|>]

Is there a way to get [Preston](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preston,_Washington) in Wolfram's GeoEntities?

Comment: `Interpreter[
  Restricted[
   "City", {GeoEntities[
     Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Washington", 
       "UnitedStates"}], "City"]}]]["Shoreline"]`

Comment: @ciao Thank you your technique works in the above cases but this is still a workaround right because AdministrativeDivision should have worked directly on the Restricted Interpreter? Also please see my updated question about not being able to find another location (a town in Washington State).